# Why does the UH60 have a titled tail rotor?

Tags: military, helicopter

I've been looking at helicopter design recently, particularly UK military helicopters. I've noticed that most tail rotors are parallel/flush with the tail of the helicopter in most designs. When looking at the UH-60, I noticed that the tail rotor is diagonal WRT the tail (see image below).

My questions are:

- Why is this?
- Does this impact it's the ability to counter torque?
- Does the rear rotor for the UH-60 have a component of lift?

[image]

Comment: This seems familiar--??

Comment: I did check similar questions when writing the title. If there's already an answer out in the ether, I apologise!

Comment: Yep, that does it! Although, from that post alone, I don't see how it can fully counter the torque without having too much rear thrust in the lift component.

Comment: @ShaunCockram check the link at the bottom of my answer in Bianfable's linked post.  It's a study of canted rotor effects.